# React-router routing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I have a react application set up using react router and two views. Login page and a Home page. I use webpack dev server for development and use and express server for production. 
If i got sequentially for example from login and then to home it works fine. But if i refresh the home page, it give me an error saying

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

And instead of the component this gets displayed on the window

> Cannot GET /home

I am confused, what's going on?

**My react-router version is 3.0.0**

[app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY5KU.png)

[webpack.dev.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaDaG.png)

Comment: You need to enable `historyApiFallback: true` for dev server in your `webpack.config.js`

Comment: Can you guide me where to do it ?

Comment: Add `devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}` inside module.exports.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: I just tried my production build, using an express server and the problem is still there. Though it has been solved on the dev environment using webpack-dev-server

Comment: That configuration will only work for `webpack-dev-server`. You need to find out similar solution for your express server.

Comment: You can use [express-history-api-fallback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback) module.